# Não contém um construtor que recebe 0 argumentos

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Meu código é

```
   public partial class TelaInicio : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm 
   {

   internal ExibirDados exibirdados = null;

    public TelaInicio(ExibirDados exibirdados)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.exibirdados = exibirdados;
    }
```

Estou tentando instanciar o form `ExibirDados` no form `TelaInicio`

classe **ExbirDados**

```
public partial class ExibirDados : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{

    public ExibirDados()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

E recebo o seguinte erro

> 'C_BuscaDinamica.TelaInicio' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

O erro em si mostra-se no `Program.cs`

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        new SplashScreen().ShowDialog();
        Application.Run(new TelaInicio()); //aqui ocorre o erro
    }
}
```

Como posso resolver isso? Porque isso acontece? por que precisamos de um construtor com zero argumentos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você instanciou `TelaInicio` usando um constructor que não requer argumentos:

```
Application.Run(new TelaInicio()); //aqui ocorre o erro
```

Porém na declaração da classe `TelaInicio` foi declarado um único constructor que requer um parâmetro da classe `ExibirDados`:

```
public TelaInicio(ExibirDados exibirdados)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.exibirdados = exibirdados;
}
```

Você têm duas opções:

1. Declarar um constructor para classe `TelaInicio` que não necessite a passagem de parâmetros:

```
public TelaInicio()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.exibirdados = new ExibirDados();
}
```

2. Passar um parâmetro da classe `ExibirDados` para o constructor da classe  `TelaInicio`:

```
Application.Run(new TelaInicio(new ExibirDados()));
```

Comment: Removi minha resposta, a sua está mais completa :-) +1